# Hyperledger v0.6 anatomy

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

As I understand, all peers are stored in fabric in VM. Each peer stores all blockchain history.

When I want to build an application I should provide an interface where a user can make a change, that change will be saved in his peer and consensus network will add that change to all peers.

It should be something like https://www.altoros.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Hyperledger-Webinar-Thomas-Marckx-architecture.jpg ?
So, each application's user send request to application(backend API) and application send request to fabric(user's peer) ?

It is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong or confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As I understand, all peers are stored in fabric in VM.

I don't understand this statement. Let me give you a summary.

A Hyperledger fabric is a network of connected peers. In v0.6, the peers can be validating (VP) or non-validating (NVP). A VP has a full copy of the world state and the transaction history in the form of a blockchain. An NVP is merely a conduit to a VP for transactions and queries. Transactions can see uncommitted state, and can thus layer upon themselves to build up a series of blocks. Queries can see only committed state (world state where the transaction is definitely in a block). This introduces hysteresis between transaction and world state changes being visible. Note that visibility has changed iun v1 fabric.

2) Each peer stores all blockchain history.

Each *validating* peer stores all blockchain history and all world state.

3) When I want to build an application I should provide an interface where a user can make a change, that change will be saved in his peer and consensus network will add that change to all peers.

An application must be built in the context of one or more smart contracts. A smart contract (also called chaincode) has an API that the architect / developer creates for transaction and query processing. The choice of API is flexible, whatever works for your application. The chaincode has access to world state, and so acts a lot like a servelet.

When you send a transaction from the application, the peer will package it up and fire it to all VPs and they will perform consensus. If this passes, the transaction will be executed on all. If there is an error on one of the peers, the transaction is failed.

There is a peculiarity in v0.6 that a failed transaction is not written into the block's transaction array. And if the transaction does not emit an event, it is also not written into the block's event array. This causes it to more or less disappear. I am not certain if there is a rejection event emitted, but I suspect not. For this reason, I always emit a success or failure event from my IoT Contract Platform (https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples/tree/master/contracts/platform) precisely so that my transactions always leave a trail in the chain.

Note that fabric v1 will fix this issue.

4) It should be something like https://www.altoros.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Hyperledger-Webinar-Thomas-Marckx-architecture.jpg ? So, each application's user send request to application(backend API) and application send request to fabric(user's peer) ?
It is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong or confirm.

The diagram is pretty free with the generalizations, but what is there is essentially correct. Each peer deploys its own copy of each chaincode in v0.6. This happens automatically because deploy also goes through consensus and is a transaction like any other. Thus, the deploy happens essentially simultaneously on all peers.

Chaincode runs in docker containers (or in process in the peer, but ignore that for your own chaincode) and communicates to the peer's docker container over gRPC through a proxy/stub arrangement called the shim.

--- NOTE ---

Fabric v1 is changing this protocol completely, as chaincode will have to be explicitly installed on any peer from which it is to be accessed. V1 has private channels (think sub-chain) that are visible to specific participants (through their captive peers, usually an endorser or orderer if I understand it so far) and so a chaincode will be deployed into a channel that is opened among the participants, but deployment can only be successful if the chaincode is already installed on the peer to be used.

It is obvious from this that there will be many possible topologies. Each participant may have a peer with many channels on each peer, but not all with the same participants. Some participants may choose to not have a peer and instead use one in the cloud or a peer on the premises of another (presumably trusted) participant. And so on.

Comment: by " As I understand, all peers are stored in fabric in VM" I mean that all peers a stored one one machine, now I understand that peers can be store one same machine but also can be on separate machines

Comment: Quite right. Peers run in docker containers, but by definition they often belong to participants and thus are running on separate machines -- virtual or physical.